# Is it a good idea to include extra libraries in jars?

Tags: java, libraries

When creating executable jars for a java project, it is possible to create jar bundle which includes all the external libraries used. It is also possible to create a jar without those external dependencies and provide the dependency path on run-time instead.

What I am wondering is which one is better? Is there a favorable way of doing it?

Comment: Do you want to put jars in jars? or do you want to explode the external jars prior to packaging (and then have only one large jar with no nested jars)? What environment are you expecting the jar to be running? Are you familiar with the class loader?

Comment: @MichaelT I don't have any specific intention. I am wondering what the best practice is. I have an abstract knowledge about the class loaders.

Comment: And that gets to the issue that durron was addressing.  The best practice varies by situation - there is no universal best practice. It depends on the type of application, the desired packaging, the users, etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### It depends.

You need to think about how your product will be used by consumers. For example, if you are creating a library that will be used by others inside Maven, then you should not include the external dependencies in the jar - let Maven handle it by providing a proper pom.

However, if instead you are deploying a completed application for non-technical users, then you absolutely do want to keep everything as simple as possible for them, and you should provide the dependencies inside the Jar.

In short, think about who your users are and what their use case would be, and then decide accordingly.

Comment: ... If you are running a war (type of jar) as a webapp, and have the container also put other jars in the search path... and its fine having wars contain jars. The other consideration is sometimes people have a common jar library that is in the class path for all of the webapps running.  There are *so* many options on how to do this.